# Enforcing the order of simulanteous event calls in C#

Tags: c#, events, race-condition

I have a C# program that has two elements, a TreeView and a DataGridView and two EventHandelrs.  When an item is selected in the TreeView, the DataGridView with a table that displays some information and can be edited by the user.  Each item in the TreeView has its own unique table.  When the user unfocuses on the DataGridView, the software underlying software model is updated (saving the changes the user made):

```
aDataGridView_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Update the software model (save the current DataGridView)
}

aTreeView_AfterSelect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Update the table that is shown in aDataGridView
}
```

My problem is that if the user de-focuses on the DataGridView by selecting a different item in the TreeView I essentially have a race condition between which of these events happens first (even though this is all on one thread).  Obviously, in this case I want the DataGridView_Leave Event to fire first or the changes the user made to the table get blown away by a new table being loaded before the changes are saved.

Is there anyway graceful way to enforce what event happens first?

Comment: I don't think you correctly understand what's going on.  While you may not be happy with the order of events, they *are* consistent.  When your code is entirely synchronous, there is no possibility of race conditions or the order of events changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you can resolve this by keeping an `isDirty` bool that is true when there are changes that must be saved. You need to track this yourself, for example in property setters. Check `isDirty` in `aTreeView_AfterSelect` and save if necessary, and in `aDataGridView_Leave` so that you don't save if there are no changes.

This should work, but it sounds like your set up is a little hacky, and it may be counter-intuitive to users that changes are saved when an element loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

What comes immediately to mind is some sort of counter. Assign each event call a number and store the last one processed. That way you can check if it is an old event and ignore it. I haven't seen it used in C# exactly, but plenty of times with AJAX when network delay often causes this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple windows form application with a treeview, gridview and text box to log events that occur.   When you leave the gridview its leave event always fires before the treeviews after select.

Are you saving the data in the gridview asynchronously?   I could see if you are saving asynchronously then the treeviews after select could fire before your async method grabbed the data to save from the grid.

If this is the case,  push the gridviews data to a stack and pop it off in the method that does the save.